# dark matter in galaxy cluster in intergalactic space

Tags: observational-astronomy, galactic-dynamics, galaxy-center, intergalactic-space

On the rotation speed of galaxies in a galaxy cluster:

-> Is the dark matter associated with each galaxy in a cluster, sufficient to explain the rotation speed of galaxies in the cluster, or extra additional dark matter in the cluster in the intergalactic space is required to explain the galaxy rotation speed in the cluster?